# Upload of GOS Attachment throws error when accessing knowledge provider

Tags: content-management-system, attachment, sap-basis

I want to upload physical files on Content with using GOS. So my BASIS consultant made some preferences for this in `OAC0`, `OAC1` tcodes etc. But now, when I try to upload a file message appears like this:

> system error when accessing knowledge provider.

Anyone have idea for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your BASIS gut improperly set up [knowledge provider](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/4c/fcc1f48d5d43f1e10000000a42189e/content.htm?current_toc=/en/65/ea8b7b4a9041ada98be49d3b89ac86/plain.htm&show_children=true) in your system.
Binary GOS attachments are stored through SAPOffice, particularly through Knowledge Providers, and *how* they are stored is maintained in transaction `KPRO`, where certain type of content server [can be specified](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/4c/ff90895b605dc6e10000000a42189c/content.htm?frameset=/en/4c/fcc40799715c4be10000000a42189e/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/65/ea8b7b4a9041ada98be49d3b89ac86/plain.htm&node_id=37&show_children=false). More info can be obtained in notes [904711](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji9viOycnQAhWiNpoKHaC4ApgQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcfile232.uf.daum.net%2Fattach%2F13385B164B31ABF12AA6EE&usg=AFQjCNFdtOLv2o-0swQyYcpR-vameyTXqg&sig2=2gbdnCvhydcRMWzaoSoilQ&bvm=bv.139782543,d.bGs) and [530297](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/530297)
However, if you are not proficient in SAP administration it's better to assign this to your BASIS. If he is not able to conduct his work, you'd better find another one:)